# Kotlinc include other jar files

Tags: kotlin, jar, kotlinc

I would like to run an app from the command line on MacOS. The problem is that I want to include `Gson` in the file to convert my data classes into a json object. (I'm new to command line with kotlin)

To simplify, I use the following:

```
fun main() {
    val item = Building(1, "Name", 4, 2)

    val jsonBuilding: String = Gson().toJson(item)
}
```

To create/run my code in the command line I use:

```
>> kotlinc creator.kt -include-runtime -d creator.jar

>> java -jar creator.jar
```

Now my question is how to include the `gson.jar` to be able to use it into the app?

Currently,  I receive errors because it cannot resolve the `Gson()`:

```
creator.kt:37:16: error: unresolved reference: Gson
   val gson = Gson()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably use Intellj IDEA. When you make a JVM Gradle command line app you should and the follow code on build.gradle.kts file.

```
tasks.withType<Jar> {
manifest {
    attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.your_project_package.MainKt"
}
// To add all of the dependencies
from(sourceSets.main.get().output)

dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
from({
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
})
}
```

Then build your project and from gradle tasks you should find Tasks->build->jar click it and that's all. You have your jar file in you project folder, build->libs->project.jar.

Now you can run your jar file as java jar file with the follow command:

```
java -jar your_project_package.jar
```

[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrX9u.png)

I hope that's helpful for you